# Xpath for when positioning is never fixed

Tags: xpath, web-crawler, screen-scraping

I've been using a specific Xpath for scraping data using a crawler. The issue is that the Xpath is looking for an "li" tag in a specific oder/position.

When other "li" tags appear before the one I'm targeting then it ruins the ordering and it returns the incorrect value.

Is there a way to setup an Xpath differently to avoid this?

The Xpath I've been using is:

```
//div[@class="info"]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/ul[1]/li[2]
```

on the below.

You'll see that the last "[2]" is always looking for the second tag to return the "thickness" value. Sometimes an additional "li" tag will appear above and it'll return an incorrect value.

```
    <div class="info">
    <div class="accordion additional-info  info__block" >
    <h5 class="accordion__header additional-info__header info__header">
    Product details</h5>
    <div class="accordion__content additional-info__content info__content" >
    <div class="info-content" id="product-details">
    <div class="info__lists">
    <ul class="info__lists-not-bullets">
    <li><strong>Length:</strong>
    3600 mm</li>
    <li><strong>Thickness:</strong>
    45 mm</li>
    <li><strong>Width:</strong>
    95 mm</li>
    <li><strong>Thickness Imperial:</strong>
    1 3/4in</li>
    <li><strong>Width Imperial:</strong>
3 3/4in</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre], and provide valid XML (or HTML?), so include all closing tags that match the opening tags (for example the closing tag of: `div class="info">`) in your example data.

Comment: The basic problem with screen-scraping is that you have to make guesses about what's going to remain constant on the page and what's likely to change. We can't make those guesses for you. But if you think the text "Thickness:" is likely to be stable, then just search for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could test the value of the child `strong` element in a predicate to see if it's `Thickness:`...

```xml
//div[@class='info']//ul[@class='info__lists-not-bullets']/li[normalize-space(strong)='Thickness:']
```

Comment: Makes sense. I was just struggling with the argument. Will also give this a shot. Thanks, Dan H!

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for something like

`//li[strong[.="Thickness:"]]/text()`

This xpath searches the entire document for `li` elements with a child `strong` element whose content is exactly 'Thickness:', then selects the child text nodes of the `li` only.

You may want to not search the entire document, in which case you would incorporate this into a more specific xpath. You may also find that 'Thickness:' isn't the same across all pages, and you'll have to adjust. Still, when dealing with elements whose positions are not fixed, it's a good idea to find some content that's stable, (potentially) like the "Thickness:" text, and anchor around that.

Comment: Thanks for this, will give it a try and feedback